# $A$ is a unitary ring with $xy=1$ implies $yx=1$, prove that if $a^2=3b^2$ and $3ab=1+4ba$, then $ab=ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(A,+, \cdot)$ be a unitary ring with the property that if $xy=1$ for $x,y \in A$, then $yx=1$. Let $a,b \in A$ with $a^2=3b^2$ and $3ab=1+4ba$. Prove that $ab=ba$.

We easily get that $(a-2b)(2a+3b)=1$, so, by hypothesis, we have that $(2a+3b)(a-2b)=1$. From here we get that $3ba=1+4ab$.

Then, $3ab-4ba=1=3ba-4ab$, and so $7ab=7ba$.

Now, $9ab=3+12ba$ and $12ba=4+16ab$, so $9ab=3+4+16ab$, thus $7ab=-7$.

Of course, we have $7ba=-7$ too.

Next, from $3ab=1+4ba$ and $3ba=1+4ab$ we get that $1+ba=3ab-3ba=-1-ab$, so $ab+ba=-2$.

We can go further and write that $aba+ba^2=-2a$ and $a^2b+aba=-2a$.

We get that $a^2b=ba^2$ and, analogously $ab^2=b^2a$.

Now, we can easily prove that $ab=6ba+5$, $ba=6ab+5$, $2ab=5ba+3$ and $2ba=5ab+3$. Here I'm stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Counterexample: $A = \mathbb{F}_7^{2\times 2}$ (the $2\times 2$ matrix ring over $\mathbb{F}_7$), $a = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$, $b = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 5 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$.

Comment: No wonder the O.P. got stuck!

Answer (score 1):

As *darij grinberg* showed this statement is generally not true. However we can prove it, if we require that  $7\not| \operatorname{Char}(A)$. For in this case we can do the following:

$$-7=7ab=7ba\implies7(ab-ba)=0$$
Now say $\alpha:=ab-ba$. We want to prove that $\alpha=0$. Now since $7\not|\operatorname{Char}(A)$ we can find $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $7x+y\operatorname{Char}(A)=1$. And so $$\underset{=0}{\underbrace{7x\alpha}}+\underset{=0}{\underbrace{y\operatorname{Char}(A)\alpha}}=\alpha=0,$$ which proves the statement.

I was not able to prove or find a counterexample, when $7|\operatorname{Char}(A)\neq7$, so that remains unknown.

Comment: I think you forgot the case char(A)=0!!!!

Comment: @npatrat $7|0$ so that case is covered.